# GMOD Lua Player death causing game to crash

Tags: lua, steam, garrys-mod

I'm working on a FFA gamemode in Garry's mod where players have to survive each other and a nextbot NPC hunting them. My override of the `GM:PlayerDeath` adequately indicates when the current round should be over, however after `SpawnGhoulInitial()` is called, any deaths cause the game to crash. Im doing all this round stuff in my roundsystem_2.lua file:

```
-- GLOBAL VALUES
roundActive = false
roundCountdownStartTime = 0
roundStartTime = 0

phase = 1
countDownLength = 5
initialGhoulDelay = 10
spawnWepDelay = 15
ghoulMadnessDelay = 20
roundLength = 30

DEFINE_BASECLASS( "gamemode_base" )

-- vector list dictionary of nexbot spawn locations per map, starting with initial spawn location
nextbot_spawns = {gm_backrooms_classic = {Vector(-7413, 318, 93), Vector(-4270, 4079, 93), Vector(-3279, -4620, 93), Vector(-11092, -4632, 93), Vector(-11086, 4316, 93)}}

function GM:UpdateTimer(time)
    net.Start("round_timer")
        net.WriteInt(time, 10)
    net.Broadcast()
end

-- function used to spawn the first ghoul of the round
function SpawnGhoulInitial()
    local name = RandomizeNextbot()
    local Ent = ents.Create(name)

    if( !IsValid(Ent)) then
        print("entity is not valid.")
        return
    end

    Ent:SetPos(nextbot_spawns.gm_backrooms_classic[1])
    Ent:Spawn()
    print("Spawned ghoul ".. name)

    PrintMessage(4, "The Ghoul has spawned. SURVIVE!")
end

-- function called to spawn the next four ghouls to sweep the map and kill off straggling players
function SpawnGhoulMadness()
    local name = RandomizeNextbot()
    local Ent = ents.Create(name)

    if( !IsValid(Ent)) then
        print("entity is not valid.")
        return
    end
    
    for i=2, 5 do
        Ent:SetPos(nextbot_spawns.gm_backrooms_classic[i])
        Ent:Spawn()
        print("Spawned ghoul madness ghoul number ".. tostring(i))
    end

    PrintMessage(4, "The Ghoul has summoned some friends. RUN!")
end

-- function called to spawn in weapons for the players
function SpawnWeps()
    for k, v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
        if (v:Alive()) then
            v:Give("weapon_crowbar", false)
            v:Give("weapon_pistol", false)
        end
    end

    PrintMessage(4, "You've found supplies. Kill other survivors!")
end

function CountAlivePlayers()
    local players = player.GetAll()
    local alive = 0

    for i = 1, #players do  
        local player = players[i]

        if (player:Alive()) then
            alive = alive + 1
        end
    end
    
    return alive
end

-- function called to give us a random nextbot to spawn in
function RandomizeNextbot()
    local names = {"table of nextbot names here, not posting them for stackoverflow because its embarrassing"}
    local random_nextbot = math.random(#names)
    return names[random_nextbot]
end

-- function called under the conditions that the round has ended, will start the next round.
function GM:EndRound(winner)    
    -- clear the map, clear sounds, print winner on screen, allow the respawning
    if (winner == nil) then
        PrintMessage(4, "Nobody Wins!")
    else
        PrintMessage(4, winner:Nick().." Wins!")
    end
    
    game.CleanUpMap(false, {})
    RunConsoleCommand("stopsound")

    timer.Remove("RoundTimer")

    timer.Create("roundEndTimer", 5, 1, function() 
        for k, v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
            if (v:Alive()) then
                v:StripWeapons()
                v:KillSilent()
            end
        end
        net.Start("round_active")
            net.WriteBool(false)
        net.Broadcast()
        roundActive = false
    end)
end

function GM:StartCountDownTimer(repetitions)
    self:UpdateTimer(repetitions)
    timer.Create("CountdownTimer", 1, repetitions, function()
        repetitions = repetitions - 1
        self:UpdateTimer(repetitions)
    end)
end

function GM:StartRoundTimer(repetitions)
    self:UpdateTimer(repetitions)
    timer.Create("RoundTimer", 1, repetitions, function()
        repetitions = repetitions - 1
        self:UpdateTimer(repetitions)

        if (repetitions <= 0) then
            self:EndRound(nil)
        end
    end)
end

--overriding playerdeath function for best death results
function GM:PlayerDeath(victim, inflictor, attacker)
    BaseClass.PlayerDeath(self, victim, inflictor, attacker)
    local players = player.GetAll()
    local lastAlive = NULL

    for i = 1, #players do  
        local p = players[i]
        if (p:Alive()) then
            lastAlive = p
        end
    end

    if (CountAlivePlayers() <= 1 && roundActive) then
        self:EndRound(lastAlive)
    end
end

-- hook for starting the round on player spawn if there are enough players.
-- countdown for round start will restart if a new player spawns in during the countdown.
function GM:DoRoundSpawn()
    --every time player joins reset the countdown
    if (CountAlivePlayers() > 1) then
        roundCountdownStartTime = CurTime()
        self:StartCountDownTimer(countDownLength)
    end
end

-- The main timing of the round. Checks against curtime to find when 
-- specific events in the round need to happen.
function GM:Think()
    -- if there is more than one player, and the time elapsed is a full 30 sec, start round
    if (CountAlivePlayers() > 1 && roundActive == false) then
        if ((roundCountdownStartTime + countDownLength) < CurTime()) then
            roundStartTime = CurTime()
            roundActive = true
            phase = 1
            
            net.Start("round_active")
                net.WriteBool(true)
            net.Broadcast()

            timer.Remove("CountdownTimer")
            self:StartRoundTimer(roundLength)
            PrintMessage(4, "The Round has begun. Last player to survive wins!")
        end
    end
    
    -- if the round is active, do this stuff
    if (roundActive == true) then
        -- if its been 10 sec since round start, spawn the ghoul
        if ((roundStartTime + initialGhoulDelay) < CurTime() && phase == 1) then
            SpawnGhoulInitial()
            phase = 2
        end

        -- if its been 30 sec since round start, spawn in weapons for players
        if((roundStartTime + spawnWepDelay) < CurTime() && phase == 2) then
            SpawnWeps()
            phase = 3
        end

        -- if its been 120 sec (2 minutes) since round start, begin the ghoul madness
        if((roundStartTime + ghoulMadnessDelay) < CurTime() && phase == 3) then
            SpawnGhoulMadness()
            phase = 4 
        end
    end
end
```

However, I do call my `GM:DoRoundSpawn` function in my `init.lua` file:

```
AddCSLuaFile("cl_init.lua")
AddCSLuaFile("shared.lua")

include("shared.lua")
include("roundsystem_2.lua")

util.AddNetworkString("round_timer")
util.AddNetworkString("round_active")

roundActive = false

playerSpawns = {--table of spawnpoints, too much to paste for stackoverflow}

function GM:PlayerSpawn(ply)
    ply:SetGravity(.85)
    ply:SetMaxHealth(100)
    ply:SetupHands()
    ply:SetWalkSpeed(250)
    ply:SetRunSpeed(450)
    ply:SetModel("models/player/Kleiner.mdl")
    
    local random_spawn = math.random(#playerSpawns)

    ply:SetPos(playerSpawns[random_spawn])

    --this section basically will make it so if someone spawns 
    --in while the round is active, they will stay dead until 
    --the round is no longer active
    print("Player: " .. ply:GetName() .. " has spawned!")
    if (roundActive == true) then
        ply:KillSilent()
        return
    end
    self:DoRoundSpawn()
end

function GM:PlayerDeathThink(ply)
    if (roundActive == false) then 
        ply:Spawn()
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

I've combed through both of these files a couple times over and I cant for the life of me figure out why deaths don't break the game until *after* the nextbot spawn happens. Is there something here I'm missing?

Comment: Comment out each line of code until you figure out which one is causing it to crash

Comment: @user253751 At least comment out the portions of code in a binary search fashion :P
Easiest way (apart from using a proper debugger) to figure out which line was last executed might be to use a debug line hook and print any line that is executed (from this script). Last line printed is where it crashed. Also is there no proper stacktrace?

Comment: @LMD I guess a game crash, not just a Lua code crash, means the whole game quits.

Comment: @LMD No stacktrace, the whole game quits, i havent been able to find anything notable in the crash dump file, either